# MATLAB How can i train NARX neural network with multi dataset

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I create NARX network for 16 input and 1 output like this

```
in=[u1(1) u1(2) ... u1(t)
    u2(1) u2(2) ... u2(t)
      .     .         .
    u16(1) u16(2) ... u16(t)];

target=[1 2 ... t];
```

and i want to train with 5 dataset of input and output, but i don't know how to create the one input and target matrix with 5 dataset to train NARX.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine datasets with

```
catsamples()
```

For example:

```
X = catsamples(x1, x2,..., xn)
T = catsamples(t1, t2,..., tn)
```

The optional parameter **'pad'** allows concatenating datasets with varying sizes.

For further informations take a look at *[catsamples](https://de.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/catsamples.html)* in the MathWorks documentation.

---

There is also a small example available at MathWorks:
[Multiple Sequences with Dynamic Neural Networks](https://de.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/multiple-sequences-with-dynamic-neural-networks.html)